# jQuery().priceFormat() gives me 0,00 when I press tab

Tags: jquery, format, price

I have an input text like this:

```
<input type="text" class="valorMinimoMaximo" />
```

And my JS defined like this:

```
jQuery('.valorMinimoMaximo').priceFormat({
    prefix: '',
    limit: 6,
    centsLimit: 2,
    centsSeparator: ',',
    thousandsSeparator: '.'
});
```

Even if I don't type anything in this input text, and press tab or click anywhere else, it gets the 0,00 value automatically. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: It happens with plain HTML as well.

Answer (score 0):

It could be usefull to specify which jQuery plugin you're using, but I will assume this is [Jquery-Price-Format](https://github.com/flaviosilveira/Jquery-Price-Format/blob/master/jquery.price_format.js), since it seems to have the same syntax than your example code.

From a quick look at the plugin source code (l. 216-222), there is a clearOnEmpty param in this plugin, that appears to do what you want, :

```
function price_it ()
{
    var str = get();
    var price = price_format(str);
    if (str != price) set(price);
    if(parseFloat(str) == 0.0 && clearOnEmpty) set('');
}
```

Comment: Can you indicate precisely which plugin (and which version) do you use ? I saw at least 3 differents ones with a quick googling.